# How to use jquery ui '.droppable' with jquery '.on' function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have three div 1, 2 and 3 within a main div i.e:

```
<div id="main">
    <div style="height:30px; background-color:yellow;" class="bnr">Banner</div>
    <div style="height:30px; background-color:yellow;" class="bnr">Banner2</div>
    <div style="height:30px; background-color:yellow;" class="bnr">Banner3</div>
</div>
```

Now, I want to append a dragged `<div class="other"></div>` after any of a `<div>` with class 'bnr', append then, when I drop on 'placeholder'. i.e when I mouse over on any of these three `<div>`, it shows a 'placeholder' in between. like I am mouse hovering on `<div> 1` and it will show a placeholder `<div>` in between `<div> 1` and `<div> 2`.

Placeholder is like:

```
<div style="height:30px; background-color:light-yellow;" class="placeholder"></div>
```

I have concluded with my try that I have to use '.droppable' function property 'over', 'out' and 'drop', instead of using, jquery's .mouseenter and .mouseleave functions.

```
$(".other").draggable({
   helper: 'clone'
});

$('.placeholder').droppable({
            over: function (event, ui) {

            },
            out: function (event, ui) {

            },
            drop: function (event, ui) {

            }
        });
```

How can I drop on 'placeholder' div?

Because its created after mouseover. So from here '.on' function comes into play. Now tell me how I can use '.droppable' with '.on' or help me to find any other solution.

Comment: The only option I see is doing this while appending/creating the dynamic elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a sample code:

```
$(".other").draggable({
   helper: 'clone'
 });

$('.bnr').droppable({
        over: function (event, ui) {
          $('.placeholder').remove();
          $('<div style="height:30px; background-color:light-yellow;"    class="placeholder"></div>').insertAfter(this);

        },
        out: function (event, ui) {

        },
        drop: function (event, ui) {
              $('.placeholder').remove();
              $(".other").insertAfter(this);  
        }
});
```

see working demo: http://jsbin.com/hoyonugupu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Its working Shadi, thanx. but another thing i forgot to mention is, these three div is visible after a click on a button, it means there will be no div earlier and these div count can be increased or decreased. it could be one div or 5 div or 10 div.  thank you and sorry!

Comment: here is an example on how to create those divs dynamically:
http://jsbin.com/vuvudamofa/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: i'm sorry once again Shadi, add one more thing, that divs are created/loaded by asp.net button. :( sorry

Comment: I suggest you open another question for that and give a clear description of your problem, however, asp.net will require a postback to the server or an ajax request to create the divs which is a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looking for a draggable which is connected to [sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/) widget having custom [`placeholder`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-placeholder) via [`connectToSortable`](https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-connectToSortable) option:

```js
$('#main').sortable({
  placeholder: 'placeholder'
});
$('.draggable').draggable({
  helper: 'clone',
  connectToSortable: '#main'
});
```

```css
#main {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
#main div.bnr {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.placeholder {
  visibility: visible;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: orange;
}
.draggable {
  width:100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div class="bnr">Banner</div>
  <div class="bnr">Banner2</div>
  <div class="bnr">Banner3</div>
</div>
<div class="draggable">Drag Me</div>
```

No need to manually inject elements and stuff, jQuery UI has inbuilt options for these interactions.

*Side note:* Please don't use inline styles.

Comment: not sortable bro, It can be 50% width div or 25% width or any width. which are 100% width right now. thanx anyways.

Comment: @LoneRay width can be controlled using CSS, I added `100%` so that the demo looks better. I don't see how that is a problem.